# Genymotion with Appium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, appium, genymotion

Group,Need a suggestion.
Creating Emulator with AVD Manager on Windows is way too slow.
Did Google around and did spin up an emulator using Genymotion.However it does not have the option of Google Chrome.Basically Google Play option itself is missing in the emulator and it does not let download the Chrome app.In my scenario I have to invoke Browser on Android and have been using the below piece of code with no luck.DesiredCapabilities

```
capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.android();
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME,BrowserType.CHROME);
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME,"Android");
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME,"testerappium");currentDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
currentDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.set(currentDriver);

return driver.get(); and then driver.get(url).
```

"browserName":"chrome","platformName":"Android","version":"","deviceName":"testerappium","platform":"ANDROID"}}

> info: Client User-Agent string: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.2 (Java/1.8.0_121)
>   info: [debug] The following desired capabilities were provided, but not recognized by appium. They will be passed on to any other services running on this server. : version, platform
>   info: Set mode: Proxying straight through to Chromedriver
>   info: [debug] Looks like we want chrome on android
>   info: [debug] Creating new appium session 38f8dafd-97d5-4aa9-ab26-7c2b4571e58b
>   info: [debug] Checking whether adb is present Is there anything I am missing.

Just getting started with Android +Appium .
Any nuggets here would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Just tried multiple things and found the solution :
Just type in adb devices.
This will spit out the device name
Use it as a part of the codebase:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.android();
                capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME,"Browser");
                capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM, "Android");


capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME,"Android");
                    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME,"device name:5555");
currentDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
                 currentDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                 driver.set(currentDriver);
```

This should solve it.